# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

This is my code:

```
# Fetch today's date
Date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
# Variable for log file 
LogFile = os.getcwd
os.mkdir("Logs3")
f = open("Password_Expiry_Date_Log_"+str(Date)+".txt", "w+")
```

I am trying to create a text file with the above specified format but am thrown as OSError. Is there a workaround to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) is a function. You need parens to call it: `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 3):

you can't have Semicolons in a file name.

```
Date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
```

change this to something like

```
Date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S')
```

Comment: You mean colon, not semicolon.

Comment: Whether colon is allowed in filenames actually depends on the filesystem, but it should be avoided in general, and if possible a cross-platform script should constrain filenames to the [Portable Filename Character Set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282). FAT32 disallows colon, and NTFS reserves it as a delimiter for file streams, i.e. "filename:streamname:streamtype", where the type must be a known type such as "$DATA". Some filesystems don't care about colon, such as the named-pipe filesystem or a VirtualBox shared folder.